# If Gal(f/K) is simple then for each extension F/K, Gal(f/F) = Gal(f/K) or trivial.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, separable-extension

I have a version of natural irrationalities theorem that states:

> Let $F/K$ be a extension of fields. Let's denote by $Gal(f/K)$ the Galois
>   group of the extension $K(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ for $\alpha_i$
>   all the roots of the separable polynomial $f \in K[X]$. Similarly for $Gal(f/F)$. Then
>   there is a group monomorphism $Gal(f/F) \to Gal(f/K)$.

From this I should deduce the following corollary:

> If Gal(f/K) is simple then for each extension F/K, Gal(f/F) = Gal(f/K)
>   or is trivial.

How can I prove that $Gal(f/F)$ needs to be normal in $Gal(f/K)$?

Comment: I think it'd be a good idea to write down what{s the relation between the (fields...?) $\;F,\,K$ ....And are $\;\alpha_i\;$ **all** the roots of $\;f\;$ ? Is $\;f\;$ an element of $\;F[x]\;$ ? Lots of info lacking

Comment: @DonAntonio all the things you asked are now in the question, do you think is complete now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true.  Indeed, by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, if $H\subseteq Gal(f/K)$ is any subgroup, then the fixed field $F=K(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)^H$ satisfies $Gal(f/F)=H$.  So to get the result you ask for, you would need $Gal(f/K)$ to have no nontrivial proper subgroups, not just on nontrivial proper normal subgroups (this is equivalent to $Gal(f/K)$ being abelian as well as simple).

Comment: would this situation change if i consider $Gal(f/K)$ as the corresponding subgroup of permutations?

Comment: No, that's an isomorphic group so nothing changes.